# combin password regex with identical characters consecutively

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have a password regex as this

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%&*])).{0,100}$
```

I wanted to add the regex which will validate this and also exclude insertion of four identical characters consecutively

I found this pattern which will give match the 4 identical characters but how do I combine them and this pattern should check there is 4 identical characters password should not be valid.

(.)\1{3}

Comment: I think you will have to use a separate test for that...

Comment: how can i check say if its not matching then password is valid (using regex)

Comment: Remove capturing group from the lookaheads (the outer round brackets) and add a negative lookahead `(?!.*(.)\1{3})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
^((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%&*]))((.)(?!\3{3})){0,100}$
```

Explanation:

```
^                     // beginning of string
(                     // begin capturing group #1 (this is actually unnecessary)
  (?=.*\d)            // must contain a digit
  (?=.*[a-z])         // must contain a lowercase letter
  (?=.*[A-Z])         // must contain an uppercase letter
  (?=.*[!@#$%&*])     // must contain a special character
)                     // end capturing group #1
(                     // begin capturing group #2: one character of password, for repetition quantifier
  (.)                 // capturing group #3: one character of password, for negative lookahead
  (?!\3{3})           // character is not followed by itself 3 times
)                     // end capturing group #2
{0,100}               // repeat group #2 up to 100 times
$                     // end of string
```